# Difference between [running-total] and [cumulative-sum]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Is there a difference between the [running-total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/running-total) and [cumulative-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cumulative-sum) tags?

Should these be merged?

Comment: They both look worthless to me

Answer (score 1):

The [running-total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/running-total) and [cumulative-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cumulative-sum) tags mean precisely the same thing. They both refer to the same underlying statistical tactic. As such, I've merged the two tags together.

I've somewhat arbitrarily chosen [cumulative-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cumulative-sum) as the "primary" tag. It gets significantly more hits on Google, and it seems to be the term of choice in several different programming environments. The choice doesn't really matter all that much, given the way our tag system supports synonyms.

This is probably not a very useful tag, and could someday be considered for removal ("burnination"), but it is not causing any harm, so I do not think that this would be a productive use of our time.