# Synonymize [running-total] to [cumulative-sum]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Both [running-total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/running-total) and [cumulative-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cumulative-sum) refer to the same statistical function and they should be synonymized.

[Previous discussion on the subject 4 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349322/)